# Cannot properly pickle file and keep getting unicode error?

Tags: python, utf-8, pickle

Hi I'm new to the use of pickle in python, and been struggling with properly pickling a file.
Say I want to pickle this file (linked file to my dropbox): 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9fyfe9e75fetfwv/tester.pickle?dl=0

I tried:

```
import pickle
file1= open('tester.pickle','rb')
tester = pickle.load(file1)
```

This gave me unicode error saying that

"ascii codec can't decode byte 0xf9"

So I've been looking around, searching and said somehow about using utf.

 
so I tried:

```
file1 = open('tester.pickle', 'rb')
tester = file.read()
text1 = tester.decode("utf8")
```

Now it doesn't call in unicode error, but when I try to read the file, it just prints bunch of x@!# numbers.

Please help me fix this!
I am totally lost.
Sorry I don't know how to directly upload the pickle file here. 

Thank you.

Comment: Where did this pickle file come from?

Comment: its from one of the task I'm trying to solve.

Comment: What is this task?  Pickles aren't generally an interchange format.  Was it saved and loaded with the same persion of python?  Of numpy?  Your pickle appears to include some sort of numpy array.